# Concatenation multiple rows SQL Server

Tags: concatenation, sql-server-2014

How do I merge rows of data from one field in a particular order

```
field A         
---------
301 
301 
301

field B    
-------
1
2
3       

field C
-------
abc
123
def
```

Desired results:

```
field A
-------
301

field C
-------
abc -- 123 -- def
```

I am a complete beginner using SQL Server 2014, so please make it clean and simple

Many thanks in advance

Kevin

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5YHf.jpg)

Comment: Will there always be three rows of data for each group?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    fieldA int,
    fieldB int,
    fieldC varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp (fieldA,fieldB,fieldC)
VALUES  (301,1,'abc'),
        (301,2,'123'),
        (301,3,'def'),
        (302,1,'ghi'),
        (302,2,'456'),
        (302,3,'jkl')
;
--Start of query to use with your data

--Common Table Expression to get the Row Numbers for fieldA
WITH preselect AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fieldA ORDER BY fieldA)'RowNum',*
        FROM #Temp)--change #Temp to your table name

SELECT a.fieldA,a.fieldC +' -- '+ b.fieldC +' -- '+ c.fieldC 'Combined Field C '
FROM preselect a --Self Joins to pivot the data                                     
     JOIN preselect b ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA AND b.RowNum = 2
     JOIN preselect c ON a.fieldA = c.fieldA AND c.RowNum = 3
WHERE a.RowNum = 1

--End of query to use with your data

DROP TABLE #Temp
```